# RxJs not understanding that filter will only keep strings

Tags: typescript, rxjs

My code is this:

```
from(new Promise(resolve => resolve(Math.random() > 0.5 ? "asdf" : null)))
  .pipe(filter(url => Boolean(url)))
  .subscribe(processLink);

const processLink = (url: string) => null;
```

TypeScript highlight `processLink` (screenshot below) saying that it cannot handle null. But my `filter` should make sure `null` never gets through. Are they types wrong? Or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: Specify the type of your promise: `new Promise<string | null>(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I come across typing issues when working with something like Rxjs, I find it easier to temporarily breakdown the chains into local variables, to identifiy where my typings are going wrong.

So for your scenario, I would first convert the code into:

```
    const processLink = (url: string) => null;
    const from$ = rxjs.from(
        new Promise((resolve) => resolve(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'asdf' : null)),
    );
    const pipe$ = from$.pipe(
        rxjs.operators.filter((url) => Boolean(url)),
    );

    pipe$.subscribe(processLink);
```

This lets me know that `from$` is being typed as `Observable<unknown>` instead of what I'd expect - `Observable<string>`. So the typings coming out of `from` is incorrect.

Depending on your preference there are a couple of ways we can hint to TS what we're after.

### Option 1:

Give a type hint to `from`:

```
    const from$ = from<Promise<string | null>>(
        new Promise((resolve) => resolve(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'asdf' : null)),
    );
```

### Option 2:

Give a type hint to `Promise`:

```
    const from$ = from(
        new Promise<string | null>((resolve) => resolve(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'asdf' : null)),
    );
```

### Option 3:

Use `Promise.resolve`, but this one may not work in your situation if your actual source promise is coming from elsewhere

```
    const from$ = from(
        Promise.resolve(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'asdf' : null),
    );
```

---

So that fixes our `from$`, but if we look to `pipe$` then we can see that it's still typed as `Observable<string | null>`, despite us `filter`-ing out the null.
Looking at the return type of our `filter` lamda, it tells us that we're returning a `boolean`, that isn't enough to tell TypeScript what we're trying to do with this filter, we'll need to specify it as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types):

```
    const pipe$ = from$.pipe(
        filter((url): url is string => Boolean(url)),
    );
```

And `pipe$` is now typed to `Observable<string>`, so our subscription is working fine.

---

Finally, we can stitch it all back together:

```
    const processLink = (url: string) => null;
    from(
        new Promise<string | null>((resolve) => resolve(Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'asdf' : null)),
    ).pipe(
        filter((url): url is string => Boolean(url)),
    ).subscribe(processLink);
```

---

If I end with multiple operators in `pipe`, which is quite common, and not sure which is going wrong, I'll comment them all out, and uncomment one-by-one, checking the type of `pipe$`, to ensure it is what I'm expecting.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion to break down to variables will help me very much in future. This is perfect answer!

Comment: Is this `filter((url): url is string => Boolean(url)),` a bit of fib though? Is it telling TS taht `url` is always a string? Because it can be string or boolean?

Comment: @Noitidart not in this instance, the return value of the filter method doesn't alter the value passed through, all it's used for is a true/false evaluation

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks again!